# Excel custom table array pattern and increments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm having trouble finding a solution that allows me to copy the same formula but increase the table array rows by increments of 15. In my first attempt I  simply tried to manually create three appropriate formulas followed by the full hand in hopes that it would catch the pattern, but I had no luck.

I'm looking for an output like this:

```
=MAX(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A2:$B17,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$E2:$F17,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$I2:$J17,2,0))
=MAX(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A17:$B32,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$E17:$F32,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$I17:$J32,2,0))
=MAX(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A32:$B47,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$E32:$F47,2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$I32:$J47,2,0))
```

I'm pretty amateur so any advise at all is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you jump from A2:B17 to A17:B32, did you mean to have row 17 in both?

Comment: Is A2 supposed to change as you copy down or is A2 supposed to be always A2 no matter what row of the copied formula you are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OFFSET` would be the function most people would gravitate to for this option.  however it is a volatile function.  Volatile functions are not the end of the world. It just means they recalculate anytime a cell on the sheet changes, even if that cell has no bearing on the volatile formula.  Regular formula only recalculate if something that affects them changes.  As a result, you can induce a lot of excess calculations by using volatile functions.  Especially if its is something copied down and reused in many cells.

The same results of `OFFSET` can be achieved using `INDEX` which is a regular formula (non-volatile).  `INDEX` is quite often assumed to return the value at a given row (1D range) and column (2D range).  What `INDEX` is actually returning in the cell address which then pulls in the value form that address.  Using this address return, you can define the start point of a range using one `INDEX` function and then using another `INDEX` function to define the end of the range.  Separate the two `INDEX` functions with a : and you now have a range!

Now lets look at the math of determining the row pattern.  Formula 1 starts in row 2, Formula 2 starts in row 17, Formula 3 starts in row 32.... and so on.  so the pattern here is essentially (Formula #-1)*15+2.  So now we just need to develop a counter that increases by one as the formula is copied down.  You could fill a column with 1, 2, 3, etc or instead you could just use `ROW(A1)`.  The first time its used anywhere it will return 1.  As it is copied down it will return 2 then 3, etc.  perfect little counter.  (Note: `Column(A1)` could be used for counting horizontally).

As stated earlier, `INDEX` takes the form of:

```
INDEX(SELECT RANGE, ROW in SELECT RANGE, COLUMN in SELECT RANGE)
```

Couple of notes:

- The row and column number are relative to the selected range and are not the same as the work sheet unless the select range starts in A1 for 2D range, or row 1 or column A for a 1D range.
- The column number is not required in a 1D selected range, only the row number.  If the selected range is horizontal, the row number is actually the column number.
- If 0 is entered for the row or column number, then INDEX takes it as returning the enter row or column of the selected range.

Lets get back to the building the formula.  Lets start by finding the starting point of the range.  So in this case we want to tell index to find A2, A17, A32, etc

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(A1)-1)*15+2)
```

And to find the end point of the range B17, B32, B47  the formula would look something like:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,ROW(A1)*15+2)
```

Now combining the two to define your range the formula would look like:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(A1)-1)*15+2):INDEX($B:$B,ROW(A1)*15+2)
```

Now that formula on its own wont look like much as you cant put more than the value of one cell in a single cell.  However it will work for your lookup formulas.  So substituting the range equation into your original formula you will have:

```
=MAX(VLOOKUP($A2,INDEX(SHEET2!A:A,(ROW(A1)-1)*15+2):INDEX(SHEET2!B:B,ROW(A1)*15+2),2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,INDEX(SHEET2!E:E,(ROW(A1)-1)*15+2):INDEX(SHEET2!F:F,ROW(A1)*15+2),2,0),VLOOKUP($A2,INDEX(SHEET2!I:I,(ROW(A1)-1)*15+2):INDEX(SHEET2!J:J,ROW(A1)*15+2),2,0))
```

Comment: I just want to thank you for the time you spent on this for me. For anyone that may use this in the future I only had some minor issues with parenthesis when pasting it into my excel sheet but otherwise this was an excellent breakdown and solution. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry about the brackets.  I caught a bunch that I repeated due to copy and pasting.  Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: +1 for "What INDEX is actually returning in the cell address which then pulls in the value" alone - understanding that INDEX returns a location is so key to being able to conceptualize solutions of this type.